# erorr api post vue laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this is my code

```
async inputschedule(){
        await axios.post('api/schedule',{
                tweet:this.text,
                schedule_at:this.data+' '+this.clock
        })
        .then((response)=>{
             if (response.status == 400){
                 console.log(response.status)
                 this.error='Il post non può essere pianificato per questa data'
             }
             
            
        })
        },
```

even if the state is 400 the variable error is not populated, what am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Whenever the `axios` instance receives a response with a statuscode out of the range of 2xx it will throw an error. [Reference](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

You can implement your functionality using the code below.

```js
async inputschedule(){
  await axios.post('api/schedule',{
    tweet:this.text,
    schedule_at:this.data+' '+this.clock
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // Handle success response.
  }
  .catch((error)=>{
    // Check whether the response was received.
    if (error.response) {
      if (error.response.status == 400){
        console.log(error.response.status)
        this.error='Il post non può essere pianificato per questa data'
      }
    }
  })
},
```

Comment: does not work :(

Comment: What does not work exactly? Could you share the error you are receiving?

Comment: Could you try removing the `await` keyword?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but the error variable doesn't populate

Comment: Are you seeing the status code being logged to the console?

Comment: no, nothing appears

Comment: Could you try: `error.response.status == 400`? I have updated the example.

Comment: does not work :(

Comment: Then please check what you are receiving from your api.

Comment: "impossibile programmare il post"  status:400Bad Request

Comment: Have you tried removing the `await` keyword?

Comment: yes i remove await